# PHP: Replace placeholders with dynamic number (delimiters, regex)

Tags: php, regex, replace, delimiter

Dear stackoverflow community,

I am currently making my own template system for a website in which I can replace template placeholders in the style of {$stuff} with php code. I have the following code for this:

```
/**
 * Replace a default placeholder.
 *
 * @access    public
 * @param     string $replace     Placeholder name
 * @param     string $replacement Text with which to replace placeholder.
 * @uses      $leftDelimiter
 * @uses      $rightDelimiter
 * @uses      $template
 */
public function assign($replace, $replacement) {
    $this->template = str_replace( $this->leftDelimiter .$replace.$this->rightDelimiter,
                                   $replacement, $this->template );
}
```

leftDelimiter and rightDelimiter in this case are {$ and }, respectively.

Now I want to add a new function that dynamically parses placeholders containing numbers - say, {$image_1}, {$image_2}, {$image_3} and lets me use the numbers contained within for my replacement code, for example so that I replace {$image_1337} with a mysql database entry from a row with id "1337".

How would I go about doing that? Extensive Google search and asking friends has, sadly, failed me due to my lack of coding vocabulary and explanation ability. It likely has to do with regular expressions, but I absolutely cannot wrap my brain around them and all attempts to construct a fitting one have failed me.

Comment: [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) might be a good place to start looking.

Comment: I think you'd be better off looking at this slightly differently. What you're doing is not a simple template assignment - you're making a helper method. So it should have it's own syntax. Perhaps something like {image(1337)}. Of course you'd still need to add new code to handle this, but I think it'll pay off in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) instead of the `str_replace`:

```
preg_replace("/\\{\\\$image_(\d).*?\\}/", "$1", $template)
```

This simple example replaces the `{$image_2}` with `2` etc.

If you need to use a real logic in your replacement you have two options:

1. The Use [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to find all instances of the pattern in the template. You can then iterate over the instances, and use plain `str_replace($match, $your_smart_replacement, $template)`
2. Use the [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) that allows callback function to generate the replacement.

Comment: Edit: Added suggestions for the "smart" replacements.

Comment: I had to use the first option because the second seems far too complex to me... with your example and that approach it works perfectly, thank you very much! However now I want to replace the {$, the "image" and the } in your example with the variables $this->leftDelimiter, $replace and $this->rightDelimiter, respectively. What do I have to change about the reg expression? Those backslashes are killing me...

Comment: Apply preg_quote on them to escape all special characters they might contain. Also please accept the answer, if it helped you :)

Comment: I wanted to update my answer with `preg_quote`, but reading again your question, it's not really clear what you envision to have in `leftDelimiter/replace/rightDelimiter`. Are `leftDelimiter` and `rightDelimiter` always `${` and `}`? And only the `replace` is the variable part? If that's correct, I believe you should change your logic to first find all template patterns (strings between `leftDelimiter` and `rightDelimiter`) and then iterate over them, testing the string between against all your possible template patterns. To be continued...

Comment: 2/2: You seem to do it other way around, by iterating over your possible template patterns and trying to find them in the template. But this cannot work once your patterns have variables. See also comment by @RobMasters (+1).